# Склонение прилагательного "буй"

Tags: склонение, прилагательные, устаревшие-слова

В "Слове о Полку Игореве" и стихотворении Державина "Вельможа" встречается прилагательное "буй", которое значит "сильный, отважный", "свирепый, дикий" или "глупый" (у Державина последнее: "Чтоб мужу бую умудриться", то есть чтобы глупому стать мудрым).

Как это слово склоняется (включая множественное число, а если есть возможность, то и двойственное)? Является ли это прилагательное кратким?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со "Словом" вопрос сложный. Надо хорошо представлять грамматику древнерусского извода, я не берусь. Скорее всего там прилагательное.
У Державина и Полоцкого - однозначно прилагательное, краткая форма, полная - буйный.
У Державина, кстати, смысл "мужа буя"  дурак, глупец. Совсем не "буйный". Сравните "буйна головушка".

В отношении склонений. Краткие прилагательные и существительные склонялись по одной схеме (что, кстати, и вызывает путаницу).

В единственном и множественном склоняется как "бой", вопросов не вызывает.

Единственное
И. **буй**
Р. **буѧ** (читается как "буя")
Д. **бую**
В. **буй/буя** - в зависимости от одушевленности
Т. **буемъ**
П. **буи** (sic!)
З. **бую/буе** - не знаю, когда что, кажется, тоже от одушевленности зависит.

Множественное
И.З. **буи/буе**
Р. **буей**/**буєвъ**/**буй** - могу только гадать, первое вернее всего.
Д. **буемъ** (У Гамановича есть еще вариант **буѡмъ**, но он, кажется, тут невозможен)
В. **буи**
Т. **буи** (**sic!**, современная форма "буями" изначально использовалась только для женского рода)
П. **буехъ**

Вот с двойственным действительно непривычно.

И.В.З. **буя**/**буѧ** - обе формы читаются "буя", я не знаю правила употребления каждой.
Р. П. **бую**
Д. Т. **буема** (**буѡма** тоже, вроде, невозможен).

Это стопроцентно по существительному. Возможно, у прилагательного были какие-то небольшие особенности, я сейчас не могу точно сказать. 
И еще. Все формы даны по *церковнославянскому* изводу, как это обычно и делается. Важно для правильного использования **e/є** и **о/ѡ**. Древнерусский же извод не был кодифицирован вовсе, но, возможно, тоже были какие-то отличия.

Для Серж.
[image: (Гаманович)]
(Гаманович)

Буй мог склоняться либо как "край", либо как "иерей", вернее всего - первое. 
Тут я, признаюсь, не силен. Но остальное - в силе. У Вас две ошибки.

(+)

Подытоживаю. У Сержа две ошибки, подчеркнуты красным.

(++)
Исправил ошибку в именительном множественного. Прошу пардону.

Answer (score 0):

В 57-й строке "Вельможи" есть слова "самолюбья лесть не обуяла б ум надменный". Обуяла, т. е. подчинила, заставила, захватила, увлекла. Может быть, "мужу бую умудриться" означает **заставить мужа взяться за ум**, если буквально, отдаться рассудку?

Кстати, и далее о том же: Ум здравый, сердце просвещенно; Собой пример он должен дать.

Есть мнение, что **Бую** не прилагательное.

Answer (score -1):

**@shampar писал** : 
<<*Есть мнение, что Бую не прилагательное.*>>                                                              Оно именно так и есть . Стихотворение Симеона Полоцкого (1629-1680 г.г.) "Монах" /[С.Полоцкий . Монах .](http://grigam.narod.ru/verseth/vers5/vers65.htm) / , в котором строки : << Мнози от вина **буи** сквернословят зело, / Лают, клевещут, срамят и честныя смело...>>     Здесь явно понимается , что <<БУЙ>> то же самое , что <<БУЯН>> , и по форме - существительное . /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Что касается "Слова о полку Игореве" , то это очень искусная поделка . Подлинность "Слова..." опровергали уже в то время , когда оно появилось , - в частности , поэт А.С. Пушкин . Современными исследователями установлен ряд несоответствий текста "Слова..." древнерусским летописям , и вывод - это произведение суть фикция .

Comment: Слово о полку не подделка. И то, что в его подлинности кто-то сомневался и сомневается, не далает его таковой. После Ваших безапелляционных высказываний комментировать Ваши суждения насчет "Буя" уже не хочется. Во всяком случае никаких аргументов в пользу того, что буй не прилагательное в стихе Полоцкого я не вижу. "Многие от виня буйны". А вот существительным считать грамматика не позволяет.

Comment: @ behemothus . Есть прилагательной <<БУЙНЫЙ>> . Так же , как край-ни-й , даль-ни-й , элоб-ны-й , несчаст-ны-й . Почему Полоцкий не написал <<мнози от вина б у й н ы>> ? Он написал  <<б у и [=буяны]>> . Просто у него в слог не вписывалось <<мнози б у и [=буяны] от вина сквернословят зело ...>> , у него такой слог стихосложения . И он переставил слова местами -  <<мнози от вина б у и ..>> . Тут <<БУЙ>>  равно <<БУЯН>> . Существительное .